# Django: correct way to pass AJAX

Tags: ajax, django

I've a view that recives parameters from the frontend via AJAX.

I've passing AJAX parameters in a maner, but this time my way didn't work.

I've asked a friend for help, and he send me another way of sending AJAX data. To my untrained eyes they both work equal. So I don't know why mine does not work:

**Why?**

**My friend's AJAX:**

```
<script>
     $("#id_shipping_province").change(function () {
        var val_d = $("#id_shipping_department").val()
        var val_p = $("#id_shipping_province").val()
        $.ajax({
            url: "/district/?d_name=" + val_d + "&p_name=" + val_p
              }).done(function (result) {
             $("#id_shipping_district").html(result);
              });
         });
 </script>
```

**My AJAX**:

```
<script>
      $("#id_shipping_province").change(function () {
         var val_d = $("#id_shipping_department").val()
         var val_p = $("#id_shipping_province").val()
         $.ajax({
              url: "/district/",
              d_name: val_d,
              p_name: val_p
          }).done(function (result) {
              $("#id_shipping_district").html(result);
           });
         });
       });
</script>
```

**View**

```
def get_district(request):
    d_name = request.GET.get("d_name")
    p_name = request.GET.get("p_name")
    data = Peru.objects.filter(departamento=d_name, provincia=p_name).values_list("distrito", flat=True)
    # data = Peru.objects.filter(provincia=p_name).values_list("provincia", flat=True)
    return render(request, "accounts/district_dropdown.html", {
        "districts": set(list(data))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the the `d_name` and `p_name` properties in a separate object specified by `data`. Currently you're passing them as top level properties of the ajax settings object, which won't have any effect.

```
var val_d = $("#id_shipping_department").val()
var val_p = $("#id_shipping_province").val()
$.ajax({
    url: "/district/",
    data: {  // Pass parameters in separate object
        d_name: val_d,
        p_name: val_p
    },
}).done(function (result) {
    $("#id_shipping_district").html(result);
});
```

The `data` object is converted into a query string and appended to the URL.

In your friend's case, they are building up the query string manually when they create the URL - hence their version works.